# How to send 1 time to different APNS URL

Tags: push-notification, passbook

I make a pushnotification to a pass. How to send to both urls with only 1 line ? I use this code: `$ConnectAPNS = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext);`
 
 `$ConnectAPNS1 = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All Passbook APNS requests should be using the production servers, so you can completely remove the 'ssl://gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195` line. To send requests for multiple devices, just write to the stream while it is open.

```
// Code edited to match info provided in the comments below.
$to_push = array();
$payload = json_encode(array('aps' => ''));

while($device = mysql_fetch_array($query2,MYSQL_ASSOC)){ 
    $to_push[] = chr(0) . chr(0) . chr(32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $device['pushToken;])) . chr(0) . chr(mb_strlen($payload)) . $payload;
}

$ConnectAPNS = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $err, $errstr, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT, $streamContext);

foreach ($to_push as $push)
    fwrite($ConnectAPNS, $push);

fclose($ConnectAPNS);
```

In the above code, replace $device_query with the object containing your devices retrieved from your database.  Also, verify that `pushToken` matches your column name, if not replace it with the correct value.

Comment: so $push = $apns_message !

Comment: If $apns_message is what contains `chr(0) . chr(0) . chr(32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $device_token)) . chr(0) . chr(mb_strlen($payload)) . $payload;` (or however you are preparing your apns messages), then yes!

Comment: $apns_message = chr(0) . chr(0) . chr(32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $to_push)) . chr(0) . chr(mb_strlen($payload)) . $payload;

Comment: Cool - so then change the name of the $to_push variable in my code above so that you don't get it mixed up with your push token.

Comment: but I get this error : [02-May-2013 11:32:59 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  fwrite() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/passesWebserver/pushNewPass/pushNotification.php on line 39

Comment: and also this too: [02-May-2013 11:34:06 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  pack(): Type H: illegal hex digit r in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/passesWebserver/pushNewPass/pushNotification.php on line 31

Comment: line 31:   $apns_message = chr(0) . chr(0) . chr(32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $to_push)) . chr(0) . chr(mb_strlen($payload)) . $payload;

Comment: Why are you putting $to_push in there?  You should have `$push1 = $apns_message = chr(0) . chr(0) . chr(32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $device_token1)) . chr(0) . chr(mb_strlen($payload)) . $payload;` and `$push2 = $apns_message = chr(0) . chr(0) . chr(32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $device_token2)) . chr(0) . chr(mb_strlen($payload)) . $payload;` then use the code above.

Comment: a for loop for each pushToken ?

Comment: so 2 pushes have same $device_token1 ?

Comment: Impossible - your iPod and iPhone will both have different device tokens. Edited my comment - the tokens should be different

Comment: Edited my comment - the tokens should be different

Comment: So I can access each pushToken from this : foreach ($to_push as $push)

Comment: so I use this: foreach ($to_push as $push) {
   // Compose and pack the push message
   $apns_message = chr(0) . chr(0) . chr(32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $push)) . chr(0) . chr(mb_strlen($payload)) . $payload;
      $success = fwrite($ConnectAPNS, $apns_message);
.....

Comment: now I use:  for($i=1; $i <= count($to_push); $i ++){
  foreach($to_push as $pushToken) {
   // Compose and pack the push message
   $apns_message = chr(0) . chr(0) . chr(32) . pack('H*', str_replace(' ', '', $pushToken)) . chr(0) . chr(mb_strlen($payload)) . $payload;
      $success = fwrite($ConnectAPNS, $apns_message);

Comment: but I get error: [02-May-2013 12:08:14 Europe/Berlin] PHP Notice:  Array to string conversion in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/passesWebserver/pushNewPass/pushNotification.php on line 38

Comment: [02-May-2013 12:08:14 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  pack(): Type H: illegal hex digit r in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/passesWebserver/pushNewPass/pushNotification.php on line 38

Comment: [02-May-2013 12:08:14 Europe/Berlin] PHP Warning:  pack(): Type H: illegal hex digit y in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/passesWebserver/pushNewPass/pushNotification.php on line 38

Comment: How to get each pushToken from array ?

Comment: Now I don't have error with pushnotification, but with getting serial method: [02-May-2013 12:54:57 Europe/Berlin] Passbook Error Log: [2013-05-02 17:54:58 +0700] Get serial #s task (for device 0f32c0e951f2f9014b998ef7e0a8a7bb, pass type pass.cam-mob.passbookpasstest, last updated 1367485532; with web service url http://192.168.1.202/passesWebserver/webService/) encountered error: Server response was malformed (The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.))

Comment: What variable is storing your raw `pushTokens`?

Comment: I use like this: $pushTokenArray = Array();
 while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($query2,MYSQL_ASSOC)){
  $pushTokenArray[] = $row2['pushToken'];

Comment: and I send serial like this :    foreach($serialsArray as $serial){
       echo json_encode(array('lastUpdated' => (string)time(), 
                           'serialNumbers' => $serial)); 
            }

Comment: Your serials code is incorrect.  $serial should be an array as per the Apple docs.  You should be sending back a single JSON dictionary containing an array of all the serials.  Your code sends a JSON dictionary for every serial number.  Also the response that you send MUST be relevant to the device.  So the iPod needs a response with Serial 1 and the iPhone needs a response containing serial 3xxxx

Comment: so how to send serial that is the same as serial in device ?

Comment: If I send array of serial, do I consider serial of device by using getting latest version of pass method ?

Comment: You need a common key between your pass table and device table.  You will get a `deviceTypeIdentifier` and a `passTypeIdentifier` in the serials request and an `authorizationToken`.  In the sample Passbook database, the key that they use for the devices table is `deviceIdentifier-serialNumber` so you if you used that approach, you could select matches for `deviceTypeIdentifier` and `passTypeIdentifier`, then explode the key to get the `serialNumber`, then look up the `serialNumber` in your pass table to get the `lastUpdated` date and return only the serials which need updating for that device.

Comment: But how you decide to do it is entirely up to you - there is no 'right' or 'wrong' way to achieve this, it needs to be whatever makes sense for how you are issuing and updating passes.  Just remember that the responses that you give need to be relevant ONLY to the device that you are responding to, otherwise you will continue to get these sort of error messages.

Comment: I change my code, but now I get another error that makes push not work  for 2 devices: [03-May-2013 10:31:19 Europe/Berlin] Passbook Error Log: [2013-05-03 15:31:19 +0700] Web service error for pass.cam-mob.passbookpasstest (http://192.168.1.202/passesWebserver/webService/): Response to 'What changed?' request included 4 serial numbers but the lastUpdated tag (1367569879) remained the same.

Comment: and then , my iPod touch get 2 passes: 1 for updating pass and 1more from pass in other device !

Comment: pass in iPhone cannot get new pass !

Comment: push works for only 1 device even there're 2 serials of passes !

Comment: 2 different passes are created but in same device !

Comment: Do both devices call your web service?  Your error message implies that your web service sent back a response with 4 serials and did not change the lastUpdated tag.  The last updated tag may be correct, but if the passes have not changed (i.e. lastUpdated = passesUpdatedSince tag), then you should send a `204` response, not an array of serials.

Comment: When I fill in updated form, I insert a new pass row. Then, I call pushnotification.php, and pass is changed, so how to make lastUpdated ! = passedUpdatedSince tag if I do like this ?

Comment: I still can push and see new updated pass, but have this error in php_error.log !

Comment: [04-May-2013 05:23:55 Europe/Berlin] Passbook Error Log: [2013-05-04 10:23:55 +0700] Web service error for pass.cam-mob.passbookpasstest (http://192.168.1.202/passesWebserver/webService/): Response to 'What changed?' request included 1 serial numbers but the lastUpdated tag (1367637834) remained the same.

Comment: now push sent to both device, but 2 passes are created in each device and only pass with serial 1 is updated in both device ! I am stuck now !

Comment: it is because it sends only 1 serial !

Comment: You could post your code and ask here. Tag it with PHP and you should get lots of quick responses

Comment: Why sometime pass is deleted automatically without unregistering task or it is because of pushnotification or what ? I get this error :[04-May-2013 06:18:24 Europe/Berlin] Passbook Error Log: [2013-05-04 11:18:23 +0700] Unregister task (for device b6f9f70c7ae632e7018866818de775b0, pass type pass.cam-mob.passbookpasstest, serial number 2; with web service url http://192.168.1.202/passesWebserver/webService/) encountered error: Authentication failure
But the unregister method works successfully when I delete pass or unregister it !

Comment: Oh, my unregister method is incorrect as data is not deleted from database !

Comment: code for unregister: if (strtoupper($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) === "DELETE"){
 $auth_key = str_replace('ApplePass ', '', $headers['Authorization']);
 $request[4] === "devices";
 $deviceID = $request[5];
 $request[6] === "registrations";
    $passTypeID = $request[7];
    $serial = $request[8];

Comment: it the same as when I register but why error is Authentication failure   ?

Comment: Why do you have `===` comparisons outside of your `if` statement?

Comment: can I use it or change to = ?

Comment: Use `=` if you want to assign a value to a variable, use `===` if you want to compare a variable to a value.  Also note that `===` is a 'typesafe comparison' That means that it will only return true if the items you are comparing have the same type and the same value - E.g. `1 === 1` is `true` but `1 === "1"` would return `false` because you are comparing an integer to a string.  You can use `==` to compare across types E.g. `1 == "1"` would return `true`.